# Metric Linear Space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask and would appreciate it if someone directed me elsewhere if this is the wrong place to ask. I'm looking for exercises where I have to prove that a space is a ***metric linear space***. This will probably come up on my exam soon and I would like to have more (difficult) examples to practice. Especially with complicated spaces and metrics (preferably with solutions too!). Do you know any book or some place where I can find exercises on this topic? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can tell us some of the examples that you know and consider easy.

Comment: I find the typical ones (like lp spaces with the lp norm, C[0,1]) easy since I have done them many times. But things I would consider hard were for example spaces which actually didn't have the metric linear property as in failed for example the continuity in multiplication condition like $d(x, y) = sup_n |x_n - y_n|^{1/n}$ on a sequence space. Or ones with more complicated spaces e.g. given by some integral. I apologize if this is vague, this is what came to my mind.